# Is there any built-in or simple way to handle non-DOM event (from EventTarget) in Blazor?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, blazor, interop

For example, a Web Permissions API's [`PermissionStatus`'s `change` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PermissionStatus/change_event)? I can obtain the `PermissionStatus` object which is an [`EventTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget). Is there any simpler way to handle `change` callback from that object? Note that this object is not in the DOM tree.

My current implementation involves using JS interop to call `addEventListener` with a handler wrapper with a `[JSInvokable]` method. The custom JS method also needs to create a function call so later `removeEventListener` can be called as well. This gets complicated really quickly and this is just one event.

I am I doing it right? Is there any built-in or better implementation that I am not aware of?

```cs
// Wrapper so JS can call it
internal class HandlerWrapper<T>
{

    Action<T> handler;
    T instance;
    public WebPermissionHandlerWrapper(Action<T> handler, T instance)
    {
        this.handler = handler;
        this.instance = instance;
    }

    [JSInvokable]
    public void InvokeHandler()
    {
        handler.Invoke(instance);
    }

}

// Add the listener
public async Task<IJSObjectReference> AddChangeEventHandlerAsync(Action<WebPermissionStatus> handler)
{
    var wrapper = new HandlerWrapper<WebPermissionStatus>(handler, this);
    var wrapperRef = DotNetObjectReference.Create(wrapper);

    var pointer = await js.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>(
        "blazorInterop.addEventListener", jsRef, "change", wrapperRef);

    return pointer;
}
```

```js
// JS interop function
addEventListener(obj, name, handlerWrapper) {
    const callback = async () => {
        await handlerWrapper.invokeMethodAsync("InvokeHandler");
    };

    obj.addEventListener(name, callback);

    return callback;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute splatting:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/splat-attributes-and-arbitrary-parameters?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Example:

```
<button @onclick="AddEvent">Add Click</button>
<button @attributes="@buttonAttributes">@buttonText</button>

@code {
    string buttonText = "No Click";

    Dictionary<string, object> buttonAttributes = new();

    void AddEvent()
    {
        buttonAttributes.Add("onclick", EventCallback.Factory.Create<MouseEventArgs>(this, NewEvent));
        buttonText = "I have a click event. Click Me!";
    }

    void NewEvent()
    {
        buttonText = "I was clicked. And I liked it.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting... I will take a look at it on the weekends. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry but after reading the article I still fail to see how this help my scenario. In my question, I stated that the `TargetEvent` object wouldn't be in the DOM. Looks like this needs to be in the DOM to work?

Comment: @LukeVo, apologies, i misread your question. This will require the element be created by Blazor. But with `jsRef` in your `AddChangeEventHandlerAsync` method, I assumed this element was created with Blazor.